# Google analytics shows wrong number of page views, asp.net website

Tags: google-analytics, asp.net

Sometimes it can be for example 4500 requests, after a few hours it shows a few thousand less. What is wrong?

It looks like analytics corrects itself.

I changed from classic to Universal a few months ago, do not know if it has anything to do with this.

In masterpage:

```
<script>
            (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
            })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'xxxxx.se');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

Comment: Do you have any filters configured on your site profile?

Comment: no, I don´t have any filters configured

Answer (score 1):

There was recently an issue where views were temporarily inflated, it sounds like you may have been affected by this.

http://www.coolsaga.com/google-analytics-double-counting-visits-page-views-other-metrics/